# Certificate for Adobe AIR Captive Runtime native application

Tags: air, certificate, signing

I have Adobe AIR application which I want to publish with Captive Runtime. I need to have it on OS X and Windows. 
I know that there are certificates for Adobe AIR, but if I'm creating MSI installer for Windows and DMG for OS X, do I need to sign those installers (purchase certificate for both Windows and OS X), or sign only AIR application (purchase single AIR certificate).

Additionally, do I need to enrol in Mac Developer Program to have it avoid any restrictions on installing on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to purchase any certificates. You can create your own certificate (Adobe Flash CC has tooling for this).

I have created MSI installers and Mac versions of my apps.

And you don't have to enroll in the Mac Developer program either.

[image: FlashProCC Publish Settings]

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to publish and test application. But for distributing purposes, I want my application to be signed properly.

Comment: @Vjeko [Code Signing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/security/WS485a42d56cd196415cc29732124ef23decb-7ffb.html)  , also you can create self signed cert with openSSL